# Generate code for nested generic enum const fields circular dependencies with Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm trying to generate code using Reflection.Emit that would look similar to what Roslyn generates for this:

```
public class MyGeneric<T>
{
    public const MyGeneric2<T>.NestedEnum c1 = MyGeneric2<T>.NestedEnum.Value1;

    public enum NestedEnum
    {
        Value1,
        Value2,
    }
}

public class MyGeneric2<T>
{
    public const MyGeneric<T>.NestedEnum c2 = MyGeneric<T>.NestedEnum.Value2;

    public enum NestedEnum
    {
        Value1,
        Value2,
    }
}
```

Experimenting with constant class field of Enum type during Reflection.Emit, shows that nested generic enum needs to be created before it can be used. But, then how [this example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgDAAhgRgNwFgBQWYGYkBMCAsgJ4DiApgHaUBOYAxgDwAqAfFgN5YCQeCRgHtqAZ2AkKNekwJt2AOgBylcZQAmAUWoBXALaDkCALySqtBozkdlq4Bu36FANQCGEHZTRYEvhHwEafQQVNS1dPR8/Hkw/BF43Dy8AGii430TPAlTYvwBfLALsTAEYIjJzGSt5bgD8YTEJCulLeVswxwMrEzMWpjbQ+3CnTMoCDFzfOoQgg0GHCLSEGLiE909kHPS/UeyloqKgA==) is nicely being compiled with Roslyn?

Here is what I've tried with nested generic type enum:

```
AssemblyName am = new AssemblyName();
am.Name = "TestAsm";
AssemblyBuilder ab = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(am, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("testmod", "TestAsm.dll");

var gt = mb.DefineType("MyGeneric`1");
gt.DefineGenericParameters("T");

var gtne = gt.DefineNestedType("NestedEnum", TypeAttributes.NestedPublic | TypeAttributes.Sealed, typeof(Enum));
gtne.DefineGenericParameters("T");
gtne.DefineField("value__", typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Private | FieldAttributes.SpecialName);
gtne.DefineField("Value1", gtne, FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.Literal);
gtne.DefineField("Value2", gtne, FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.Literal);

// First we need to create MyGeneric type before we can create NestedEnum
gt.CreateType();
var ct = gtne.CreateType(); // If we were to execute this before previous line, exception would be thrown

var mt = mb.DefineType("MyTest");

// Here we can safely use ct since it is created type.
mt.DefineField("sfield1", ct.MakeGenericType(typeof(int)), FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.Literal).SetConstant(1);

// Next line fails since we must use fully created type and not type builder
mt.DefineField("sfield2", gtne.MakeGenericType(typeof(int)), FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.Literal).SetConstant(1);
```

So, how would one create constant of another type that is not yet created?